# Where in the Callable Statement stays the registerParameterOut?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, junit, integration-testing, callable-statement

I'm trying to make a integration test for a method that a call a procedure, the values are coming, but I just want to know where in the callableStatement variable is the value of the registerParameterOut, because I want to mock, after the return, a value in one of the index, to force a success test, I don't know a way to do it, I tried things like this:

**TestMethod**

```
@Test
public void returnSucess() {
    ExampleClass example = ExampleClass.createExample();
    ArrayList<String> mock = new ArrayList<>();

    mock.add("14");
    mock.add("1234");
    mock.add("331");
    mock.add("000");
    mock.add("Test");
    mock.add("Test");
    mock.add(null);


    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> {
        when(mapper.toCallProcedure(example)).thenReturn(mock);
        given(callableStatement.getObject(13)).willReturn("00"); //Tried with when too, and using getString(13)... But it couldn't change the value
        adapterOut.Method(example);
    });
}
```

**The way that I call the proc**

```
stmt = conn.prepareCall(Query);
        stmt.setString(1, value1);
        stmt.setString(2, value2);
        stmt.setString(3, value3);
        stmt.setString(4, value4);
        stmt.setString(5, value5);
        stmt.setString(6, value6);
        stmt.setString(7, value7);

        stmt.registerOutParameter(8, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(9, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(10, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(11, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(12, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(13, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(14, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(15, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(16, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(17, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

        try {
            stmt.executeQuery();
```

I tried to put a breakpoint after executeQuery, and search for the values of registerOutParameter, but I couldn't find it, the only way to take the values is using getObject(index) or getString(index). (When I try to use stmt.getResultSet() the return is null and trying to use something that I saw here in stackOverflow `ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(index)` it's throwing a exception that can't convert java....sql to ResultSet or something like that).

There's a way to get the change the value in real time of execution or mocking in the integration/unit test?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Note: invoking `registerOutParameter()` is a matter of one-time set up for the statement.  It is answering the question "which of the statement parameters are output parameters of a stored procedure?"  That does not change across multiple uses of the statement, so if you retain and reuse the statement then you do not need to perform that registration on a per-use basis.

Comment: And of course, `CallableStatement` itself is an interface.  It does not itself provide storage for anything.  You would need to look at the object (provided by your JDBC driver) that *implements* that interface.

Comment: But if the point is to provide a mock, then why do you even need to know?  Interpose a wrapper that customizes `getObject()` (or whatever other method(s) you choose) to your liking, or else mock up a whole instance from scratch.

Comment: I tried to create a mock for the return value, but i had problems to create a result set mock (for the callable statment), but a wrapper for the method I didn't tried, it could be a possible solution...

Comment: Are you really trying to mock interaction with a stored procedure that returns a `ResultSet` via an out parameter?  Such SPs do exist, but they are uncommon, and the exception you report suggests that yours is not one of them.  In that case, the `ResultSet` is a false trail.

Comment: What do u sugest for this mock?

Comment: Figure out what the correct way is to retrieve the wanted out parameter(s) from the statement.  This is a function of the stored procedure you are calling.  Then mock that.  It is unlikely that that will require a mock of `ResultSet`.

Comment: Could you please provide any example of this in practice?